# App Engine DateTimeProperty averaging

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime, average

I am trying to take two `DateTimeProperties` and find the difference in Hours, minutes, and seconds between them. I am also trying to take the difference between the two instances and average them against other instances. Is there an easy way to do this?  If someone could post a solution, that would be excellent!

My Model:

```
class Submission(DictModel):
    timeIn = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=False)
    timeOut = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=False)
    UUID = db.StringProperty()
```

In the end, I am trying to take an average of all `Submissions`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateTimeProperty's underlying [value type](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#DateTimeProperty) is python datetime.datetime. Just subtract them to get [difference](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)

```
    dt = Submission(timeIn=datetime.datetime(year=2014, month=1, day=20, minute=5, hour=9),
                    timeOut=datetime.datetime(year=2014, month=2, day=25, minute=10, hour=10))
    diff = dt.timeOut - dt.timeIn
    self.response.write(diff.seconds)   # get seconds
    self.response.write(diff.days)    # get days
```

Comment: `diff.seconds` is not the total seconds - you want `diff.total_seconds()`.

Answer (score 1):

The datastore is not a relational database and does not allow you to do things like aggregation. If you need to calculate things like averages across the whole data set, you need to use the [mapreduce framework](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/), which uses offline tasks to run a mapper over each entity in a kind.